# Converting JSON to CSV w/ Pandas Library

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I'm having trouble converting a JSON file to CSV in Python and I'm not sure what's going wrong. The conversion completes but it is not correct. I think there's an issue due to the formatting of the JSON file; however, it's a valid JSON.

**Here's the content of my JSON file:**

```
{
    "tags": [{
        "name": "ACDTestData",
        "results": [{
            "groups": [{
                "name": "type",
                "type": "number"
            }],
            "values": [
                [
                    1409154300000,
                    1.16003418,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1409154240000,
                    0.024047852,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1409153280000,
                    10.25598145,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1409152200000,
                    10.73193359,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1409151240000,
                    0.024047852,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1409080200000,
                    14.34393311,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1409039580000,
                    4.883850098,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1408977480000,
                    5.520019531,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1408977360000,
                    0.00793457,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1408974300000,
                    2.695922852,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1408968480000,
                    0.011962891,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1408965720000,
                    0.427978516,
                    3
                ],
                [
                    1408965660000,
                    0.011962891,
                    3
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Here's what I tried:**

```
import pandas as pd
json_file = pd.read_json("QueryExportTest2.json")
json_file.to_csv()
```

**Here's my output:**

`,tags\n0,"{u\'name\': u\'ACDTestData\', u\'results\': [{u\'values\': [[1409154300000L, 1.16003418, 3], [1409154240000L, 0.024047852, 3], [1409153280000L, 10.25598145, 3], [1409152200000L, 10.73193359, 3], [1409151240000L, 0.024047852, 3], [1409080200000L, 14.34393311, 3], [1409039580000L, 4.883850098, 3], [1408977480000L, 5.520019531, 3], [1408977360000L, 0.00793457, 3], [1408974300000L, 2.695922852, 3], [1408968480000L, 0.011962891000000002, 3], [1408965720000L, 0.42797851600000003, 3], [1408965660000L, 0.011962891000000002, 3]], u\'groups\': [{u\'type\': u\'number\', u\'name\': u\'type\'}]}]}"\n`

This isn't right, because when I put it into a new Excel CSV doc instead of just printing it, the CSV is all in one cell.

**If it helps, when I try this:**

```
import json

with open('QueryExportTest2.json') as json_data:
d = json.load(json_data)
print(d)
```

**I get this:**

`{u'tags': [{u'name': u'ACDTestData', u'results': [{u'values': [[1409154300000L, 1.16003418, 3], [1409154240000L, 0.024047852, 3], [1409153280000L, 10.25598145, 3], [1409152200000L, 10.73193359, 3], [1409151240000L, 0.024047852, 3], [1409080200000L, 14.34393311, 3], [1409039580000L, 4.883850098, 3], [1408977480000L, 5.520019531, 3], [1408977360000L, 0.00793457, 3], [1408974300000L, 2.695922852, 3], [1408968480000L, 0.011962891, 3], [1408965720000L, 0.427978516, 3], [1408965660000L, 0.011962891, 3]], u'groups': [{u'type': u'number', u'name': u'type'}]}]}]}`

How can I convert this nested JSON to CSV properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is a nested dict (with lists and other dictionaries). I guess that you are interested in the `values` section of the `json`. If my assumption is correct, since this is a single entry json, try the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_str['tags'][0]['results'][0]['values'])
df.columns = ['var1','var2', 'var3']
df.to_csv(filename)
```

If you will have more records you will have to iterate over the lists of values, namely you could append them.

```
all_results = json['tags'][0]['results']
for i in range(0, len(all_results))
    if i == 0:
        my_df = pd.DataFrame(all_results[i]['values'])
    else:
        my_df.append(pd.DataFrame(all_results[i]['values']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. When I tried this, however, I got an error saying "KeyError: 'values'. I'm assuming this means that this key is not in the dictionary-- how would I add it? (I am new at using Python)

Comment: I had a typo in the second part of my answer, now its updated,maybe that was causing the error.
Hmm.. if you are getting that error with the json you posted, you should be accessing that key in the incorrect way since I was able to do it from my end. If it's a new json, the way to add to a dictionary is `my_dict['values'] = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` for example. Here you add specific values

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to get in the end? The problem here is that your json is nested, if you for example try doing something like this:

```
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(jour_json['tags'])
```

you will get dataframe with two columns - name and result.

Comment: I want to have a CSV with three columns comprised of the 'values', for example for the first record: Column 1: 1409154300000, Column 2: 1.16003418, and Column 3: 3 .